# MobileFirst 8.0 view browser version of app on a remote server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have my mobile app and a webversion in the console. In 7.1 you could just click a url and see the web version of the app.  IBM removed this link in 8.0. So how do I see my browser version on a remote server now?

[The IBM docs have you using](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/web/) node.js to do it by modding the server.xml file but that is just silly for non-devs to use. How would a tester access this from a url?   So I am looking for  www.myurl.com:443/[my app name and index page maybe?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `browser` platform to your Cordova project and host it in the same server as MobileFirst. See 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/09/07/cordova-browser-compatibility-with-MFP/

Comment: I have already added the browser version of the app to my console. End-users will not have npm or mfp run browser.  How do end-users run the browser version from their home computer when the app is deployed to a remote server?

Comment: You will have to host the web app which end users can access via an URL.
The same post has information on how to host your web app towards the end of the post.